# Save userId in sessionStorage giving error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to store the variable "clients[i]._id" and send it to another page when I click the button in the for loop.I want to later use that id to get more specific information about that client on its seperate window.

Im getting an undefined error where clients is undefined. Also the console.log in the store(function) doesnt work. Can you find whats wrong?

```js
let thisArray = [];
//let clientId = $('#clientId').val();

$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/auth/clientsGET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(clients) {
    thisArray = clients
    buildTable(thisArray);
    console.log(thisArray);
  }
})

function buildTable(clients) {
  let table = document.getElementById('tabelaClientesAdmin')

  for (let i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
    let row = `<tr>
      <td>${clients[i]._id}</td>
      <td>${clients[i].name}</td>
      <td>${clients[i].admin}</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="store()">Ver Cliente</button></td>
    </tr>`
    table.innerHTML += row
  }
}

function store() {
  console.log("Trying to get clientId....")
  
  let clientId = clients._id;
  sessionStorage.setItem("clientId", clientId);
  location.href = "./ver_cliente";
}
```

I'll update straight away when information is needed.

Comment: `clients` is not in scope of the `store()` function. Even if it was, from the context it's used in other locations it appears to be an array, so you need to access it by index before retrieving the `_id` property from it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so it's only in the scope of buildTable because he got it from the ajax get correct? And I cant pass it to store() because I need to access by index first ? (Trying to understand)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the index like that:

```
onclick="store(${i})"
```

then retrieve it like that:

```
function store(index) {
  const clientId = thisArray[index]._id;
  sessionStorage.setItem("clientId", clientId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly modified but working example of your page:

The most important part is probably:

```
let clientId=+ev.target.closest("tr").children[0].textContent;
```

where I navigate from the clicked button (`ev.target`) via the parent-`<tr>` to the first child (a `<td>`). There I read the `textContent`, convert it into an integer with the unary `+`-operator and store it in variable `clientId`.

I also introduced the global variable `clients` that could be used for further reference in the page. But currently this array not really used anywhere.

```js
var clients
$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(d) {
    clients = d
    buildTable(clients);
    console.log(clients);
  }
})

function buildTable(clients) {
  let table = document.getElementById('tabelaClientesAdmin')

  for (let i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
    let row = `<tr>
      <td>${clients[i].id}</td>
      <td>${clients[i].name}</td>
      <td>${clients[i].username}</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Ver Cliente</button></td>
    </tr>`
    table.innerHTML += row
  }
}

document.body.onclick=function(ev) {
 if (ev.target.tagName==="BUTTON") {
  let clientId=+ev.target.closest("tr").children[0].textContent;
  console.log("Trying to get clientId:",clientId);
  // sessionStorage.setItem("clientId", clientId); // not in SO snippets
  console.log("go to ./ver_cliente");
}}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabelaClientesAdmin"></table>
```